# How to Show Stack Traces in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, stack-trace

This seems like a really simple question but, as with many things ZF2, I cannot seem to find an answer.

I am learning to use ZF2, after having developed in ZF1 for years. I am following the tutorials but finding it quite frustrating as when I have an error or bad configuration I just get a blank page - no clues, no stack trace.

In ZF1 to print errors and stack traces to screen you could add the following line in .htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

and in application.ini

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1 
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

How do I do this in ZF2??

I see no way to turn on a development mode?

I tried adding the following to local.php but always just get a blank page when something goes wrong and need to check the Apache2 log file to see what the problem was:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    ),
```

Comment: Are you using ZF 2.1 already? As 2.1 covers view-script-errors, too, which are usually the cause for blank screenies currently ;)

Comment: I searched for 'ZF2 "view-script-errors"' on Google and got 3 results..? None of which seemed to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `local.php` to `debug.local.php` (or something.local.php).

I'm guessing it's not being picked up by the auto load pattern in `application.config.php`:

```
'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
```